# Is it possible to install Ubuntu and remove Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

Is it possible to install Ubuntu and delete Windows? I don't want to dual-boot and I'm not sure whether Ubuntu needs an OS on my computer to operate.

---

Ok. I have installed Ubuntu's latest version . It goes well until I move my mouse on the Desktop, then I get a broken image.

Comment: You should accept the answer below if you found it useful, then you should ask a new question for your new problem rather than updating this one. If you can't include images, leave the plain link in the new question and drop me a comment by including @kos in the body of your comment and I'll add the image for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Yo have to choose "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" in "Installation Type" step.